# Famous android unbound prefix error

Tags: android, xml

I am following the example in the book "Beginning Android 4" and I am getting an xml parsing error. Apparently many people have the same issue but I cannot find a posting that is similar to the books example. Below is my code. The unboudn prefix hits at the second radio group...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 

    <RadioGroup android:id="@+id/orientation"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp">          
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/horizontal"
            android:text="horizontal">
        </RadioButton>
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/vertical"
            android:text="vertical">
        </RadioButton>
    </RadioGroup>  
    <RadioGroup android:id="@+id/gravity"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        andorid:padding="5dip">         
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/left"
            andoid:test="left">
        </RadioButton>
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/center"
            android:text="center">           
        </RadioButton>    
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/right"
            android:text="right">
        </RadioButton>   
    </RadioGroup>        
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have couple of errors in your second radiogroup

```
 andorid:padding="5dip"
```

Change this to

```
 android:padding="5dip"
```

Note the change from `andorid` to `android` and

```
  andoid:test="left"
```

to

```
 android:text="left"
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! Now I really know what to look for. I was looking above that area. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

```
andorid:padding="5dip">
```

the prefix andorid is unbound. I think you mean

```
android:padding="5dip">
```

Answer (score 1):

You have typo'd android several times in your document, which is the attribute's prefix. See:

```
andorid:padding
```

instead of

android:padding